# How to change location by updating only path element in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Given simple route example:

```
.when('/invoices/page/:number', {
    templateUrl: 'invoices-list.html',
    controller: InvoiceController,
    resolve: InvoiceController.resolve
})
```

How do I set location to given page, without setting the whole path by hand. I can obviously do `$location.path('/invoices/page/' + $scope.currentPage);` but I would like to reuse given mechanism for other resources as well, and avoid messing directly with the strings.

It's trivial to solve, when the page number is a search parameter, then it is enough to use `$location.search("number", $scope.currentPage)` Is there equally trivial way to redirect if the parameter is part of the path?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$location.$$path='/invoices/page/' + $scope.currentPage;
```

and if you want to reload the page then use with the below code

```
$route.reload();
```